# <T extends SomeClass> not returning The object as type T. Can't find solution working for me

Tags: java, generics, extends

I have the following class. I'm trying to make it so that getConfig() will return the type specified, however, it only returns as BaseConfig. Let's say I have MyConfig that extends BaseConfig, I'd like for the method to return MyConfig instead of BaseConfig. Would really appreciate any help as I can't seem to find the appropriate solution that works for me.

```
public class LoadedMap<T extends BaseConfig> implements GameMap {
    private File world;
    private Class<T> configClass;
    private T config;

    public LoadedMap(File world, Class<T> configClass) {
        this.world = world;
        this.configClass = configClass;
        this.loadConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public File getWorld() {
        return this.world;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMapName() {
        return this.config.getMapName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMapAuthor() {
        return this.config.getMapAuthor();
    }

    public <T extends BaseConfig> T getConfig() {
        return configClass.cast(config);
    }

    private void loadConfig() {
        this.config = JsonConfig.load(new File(world + File.separator + "map.json"), configClass);
    }
}
```

Some additional classes that make up the system I'm working on:

```
public class MapManager<T extends BaseConfig> {
    private Class<T> configClass;
    private List<LoadedMap<T>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    private LoadedMap<T> current = null;

    public MapManager(Class<T> configClass) {
        this.configClass = configClass;
    }

    public CycleCompleteEvent cycle() throws MapNotFoundException{
        load();
        if (maps.size() == 0) {
            throw new MapNotFoundException();
        }

        LoadedMap previous = current;
        if (maps.contains(current) && maps.indexOf(current) != maps.size() - 1) {
            current = maps.get(maps.indexOf(current) + 1);
        } else {
            current = maps.get(0);
        }

        MapSelectedEvent mapSelectedEvent = new MapSelectedEvent(current);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(mapSelectedEvent);

        if (mapSelectedEvent.getMap() != null) {
            current = mapSelectedEvent.getMap();
        }

        init();
        if (current != null) {
            clean(previous);
        }

        CycleCompleteEvent cycleCompleteEvent = new CycleCompleteEvent(current);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(cycleCompleteEvent);
        return cycleCompleteEvent;
    }

    private void init() {
        prepareWorld();
    }

    private void init(LoadedMap<T> map) {
        if (current != null) {
            clean(current);
        }

        current = map;
        prepareWorld();
    }

    private void prepareWorld() {
        WorldCreator creator = new WorldCreator(current.getWorld().getName());
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new PreMapLoadEvent(current, creator));
        World world = Bukkit.createWorld(creator);
        world.setAutoSave(false);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new PostMapLoadEvent(current, world));
    }

    private void clean(LoadedMap map) {
        if (Bukkit.getWorlds().contains(map.getWorld().getName())) {
            Bukkit.unloadWorld(map.getWorld().getName(), false);
        }
    }

    public void load() {
        File worldContainer = Bukkit.getWorldContainer();
        for (File file : worldContainer.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                    if (f.getName().equals("map.json")) {
                        for (LoadedMap loadedMap : maps) {
                            if (loadedMap.getWorld() == file) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        maps.add(new LoadedMap<>(file, configClass));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Class<T> getConfigClass() {
        return configClass;
    }

    public List<LoadedMap<T>> getMaps() {
        load();
        return maps;
    }

    public LoadedMap<T> getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }
}
```

And another:

```
public abstract class Game<T extends BaseConfig> extends BukkitRunnable {

    private Plugin plugin;
    private boolean cancelled = false;
    private MapManager<T> mapManager;

    public Game(Plugin plugin, Class<T> configClass) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.mapManager = new MapManager(configClass);
        this.runTaskTimer(plugin, 1, 1);
    }

    public abstract void run();

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        if (this.cancelled) {
            return;
        }

        this.cancelled = true;
        Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(getTaskId());
    }

    public Plugin getPlugin() {
        return plugin;
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }

    public MapManager getMapManager() {
        return mapManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the object instance which you're calling `getConfig()` on?  It should be created like `new LoadedMap<MyConfig>(...)`

Comment: may be this will help you understand it a bit better?  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133984/how-to-return-generic-type-from-same-method-for-parent-and-child-classes

Comment: Alex. JsonConfig uses gson to load the config as the type I want, however, due to the fact its an api it needs to be generic for modules and their individual configs.

Additionally, all configs must extend BaseConfig as the api also handles some common configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You're making your method generic, but it shouldn't be: the class is generic already. It should simply be declared as

```
public T getConfig() {
    return configClass.cast(config);
}
```

That way, the type T returned by the method is the type T defined at the class level. The way you did it, T was another generic type, specific to the method that happened to have the same name as the class generic type but wasn't the same. I.e. it was equivalent to

```
public <U extends BaseConfig> U getConfig() {
    return configClass.cast(config);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to change anything. Still returns BaseConfig for whatever reason.

Comment: Added a couple more classes for you to look at.

Comment: But you didn't say what the problem was with those classes. Tell us precisely what you expect some piece of code to do and what it does instead.

Comment: The problem is with getConfig(). I expect it to return an object of type ArenaConfig, which extends BaseConfig, however everything I've tried still results in getConfig() returning a BaseConfig object.

Comment: I can't find any reference of ArenaConfig in the dozens of line of code you posted. Post the relevant code.